# Flagging a "temper tantrum" downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

I was engaging in a 'dialogue' with a user on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508965/powershell-join-items-in-an-array) and after explaining why his answer wasn't valid, he deleted his answer, and to all appearances downvoted in a fit of pique that I pointed out that he was wrong.
I wouldn't think that this is acceptable behavior, and I don't currently suspect that it will result in 'downvote vendetta', but it's not the first time I've seen apparently reasonless downvotes for answers I've submitted in various SE areas.

Is there any way to easily flag the moderators in a case like this?

Comment: Very unlikely you got these downvotes from that user.  Ticked-off users never wait twenty minutes between votes.  Do nothing.

Comment: No, the first downvote on my answer appeared to me to be simultaneous with the other user deleting his answer, shortly after I posted yet another comment elaborating on why I felt his answer did not meet the OP's requirements. I do understand now that I was operating on an invalid assumption, per Stijn's answer below.

Comment: [related Q/A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262636/downvoted-after-voting-to-close-a-question?rq=1)

Comment: None of the votes were simultaneous with the deletion.  You in fact got an upvote shortly after the deletion, about equal to the reading time of your post.  So most likely explanation is that you got it exactly bass ackwards.

Comment: OK, you obviously have access to information that I don't; I was reporting what I saw as a user. Not trying to make a big issue of it, just was a little irked at the apparent timing, and felt that clarification was more-or-less appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption that downvoting for a "wrong" reason is a flaggable offence, is not correct. It may not be desired behaviour, but it certainly isn't unacceptable behaviour.

The only exception is when it concerns [serial voting](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) that isn't detected by the system, then you may flag one of their posts or comments (or one of your own) for moderator attention.

Comment: OK, I hadn't realized that there wasn't a 'tighter' code of conduct. I don't have to like it, but if that's the way it is, that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the downvoter is the other author, maybe Not.

Unless you get random downvotes on your answers after argument with someone there's no reason to flag it for moderator attention.

Everyone is free to vote as they feel (useful or not useful) and that doesn't warrant a mod flag.

In case there's something really suspicious you can flag one of your own post concerned and in the text box take care of putting enough details on the why you're flagging to save the moderator from the need of guessing the reason.

Comment: Good point about flagging one of your own posts, sometimes that's the only possibility.